# How to match patterns stored in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to setup a system where I can store phrases containing data placeholders in a table that can be matched by a user's input string.  For example, `today is [date]` would be stored in a column and potentially positively matched with the phrase `today is Tuesday`.  The solution would need to be fast.  Backend is MSSQL and .NET.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest writing some code in .NET to do it.

Comment: Do you need to store 'today is [date]' or can you just store 'today is' and have another column indicating the '[date]' part?

Comment: This is going to be used for phrase matching.  I wanted to include the placeholder in the text to denote the type of data that is expected in that location.

Answer (score 0):

Your matching options in SQL look like:

```
WHERE ColumnName = 'today is Tuesday'
```

or

```
WHERE ColumnName LIKE 'today is %'
```

or

```
WHERE ColumnName IN ('today is Monday', 'today is Tuesday', 'today is Wednesday')
```

Any of those will be fast.  So you could use .NET code to build an IN list with all of the potential placeholder replacements.

Just beware of a query like:

```
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '% is today'
```

This will be slower because the leading wildcard makes it impossible for SQL Server to use a ColumnName index (if one exists), and it will instead perform a table scan.